# How can we connect a mobile to a pc using a Java program.?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

I'd like to write a JAVA program that connects my mobile with PC through a USB cable. How do I go about it??

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if there is an API and read it. If there is no API, have fun figuring out what the protocol is that you need to use.